# jquery: set image width but no larger than original size?

Tags: jquery, image, resize

hey guys,
i wonder how to solve this:

```
function setimgwidth() {
    var bw = $('.post-body').width();
    $(".post-body p img").each(function() {
        var os = $(this).width();
        //if (bw < os) {
            $(this).removeAttr('height');
            $(this).width(bw);
        //}
    });
}
```

basically my .post-body div is dynamically asdjusted to the screensize.
every image inside of it should as well be resized to the width of the .post-body div, but only if the .post-body is NOT larger than the original size of the image. i don't want the image to get blurry.

as for now it actually works almost like i want it to. the function is called on window resize. however if the .post-body is larger than the actual image-size the image gets still enlarged.

if I uncomment the code above it seems to work, but only if i resize the window to a smaller size. if it's resized larger the image will not adjust anymore and stay small.
that's probably because the original size gets overwritten every time i call the function.

somehow i can't find a proper solution and i need your help, please.
thank you in advance,
matt

Comment: Do your two commented out lines not work? What happen's when they're uncommented, as opposed to when they are commented? (They look right to me)

Comment: well, it does kind of work, but only if i REFRESH the window. if i resize and make it smaller, the image resizes properly, however as soon as i drag it larger the image does not enlarge anymore!

Comment: Can you confirm that your event is firing on each window resize and not just when the window loads? Can we see you code somewhere?

Comment: if I uncomment the code above the part inside is just fired if the window resize makes the window smaller. somehow the os variable gets overwritten with every call of the function.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense then. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having when trying to resize the window to make it larger (and hence the div and hence the image) is that the original image size is being lost.

The following code needs to run after the DOM has loaded and the images have width (may need to happen after `.load()`)

```
$(".post-body p img").each(function() {
    // Save the original image width
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
});
```

The folowing code needs to run on the window resize event (like you currently do):

```
function setimgwidth() {
    var bw = $('.post-body').width();
    $(".post-body p img").each(function() {
        // Check the width of the original image size
        if (bw < $(this).data('width')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('height');
            $(this).width(bw);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: that might not work because the closest element is a paragraph which has a fixed with of 650px.

Comment: It's looking for the closest element that matches `.post-body`, not the closest element (unless that element has a class of "post-body").

Comment: does not work, same happens. just the making the window smaller does the job, making it bigger doesn't do anything.

Comment: Answer completely re-written now that the question has been explained further in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're measuring the image's width after it has loaded. So if you just try `$('#my-img').width()` in normal jQuery code, it'll probably return 0 (unless you have the width attribute or the width style set) because the ready event doesn't wait for images to have loaded. `$('#my-img').load(function () { /* do something */ });` should do it.